# How to prove that the area of a rectangle whose sides, and diagonal are positive integers is multiple of 12?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation

What I observed is that the two adjacent sides and the diagonal must be a Pythagoras triplet. I don't know how to prove that formally.

Comment: By looking at the possible square numbers and their sums mod $3$ and mod $8$, you can show that in any primitive Pythagorean triple, at least one leg must be divisible by $3$ and one leg must be divisible by $4$ (could be same leg) -- which implies the same for any Pythagorean triple. Since $3$ and $4$ are relatively prime, the product of the legs must be divisible by $12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2.$$

Square of a number gives $0$, or $1$ mod $3$. If $c$ is divisible by $3$ then $a, b$ should also be divisible by $3$. At least $a$ or $b$ is divisible by 3. If $c$ is even then both $a$ and $b$ should be even (RHS divides $4$) which proves our statement. If $c$ is odd then either $a$ or $b$ should be even. WLOG suppose $a$ is even and does not divide $4$ then we have $$a^2=(c-b)(c+b)$$
$b$ and $c$ are of the form $4k+1$ or $4k+3$. In all cases RHS divides $8$ so LHS should also. Therefore $a$ divides $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$.

WLOG $a$ is even and $b$ and $c$ are odd.

$a^2=(c-b)(b+c)$.

Suppose a prime divided $(c-b)$. Then if it also divided $(b+c)$, it must divide $2b$. That in turn implies it divides both $b$ and $c$ which contradicts their being relatively prime. If the product of two relatively prime integers is a perfect square, each factor must itself be a perfect square.

So we have:

$c-b=2n^2$

$b+c=2m^2$

This implies:

$ab=(2mn)(m^2-n^2)=2mn(m-n)(m+n)$

If $gcd(m,n)>1$, then $b$ and $c$ also have a common factor, a contradiction. If $m$ and $n$ are both odd then $b$ and $c$ are both even, another contradiction, so $m$ and $n$ are neither both even or both  odd.

Since either $m$ or $n$ is even, $a$ must be divisible by 4, then so is $ab$.

Now we can consider some cases.

Case 1: either $m$ or $n$ is divisible by 3. Then so is ab so ab is divisible by 12.

Case 2: Neither $m$ or $n$ is divisible by 3. If a number is not divisible by 3, then it is either 1 more or 1 less than a multiple of 3. If two numbers are both 1 more or 1 less than a multiple of 3, then their difference is divisible by 3. If one number is 1 more than a multiple of 3 and another number is one less than a multiple of 3, then their sum is a multiple of 3.

If follows that the product of two integers, their sum, and their difference must be divisible by 3. So $ab$ is divisible by 3.

Since $ab$ is divisible by 3 and by 4, it is divisible by 12.

Since this applies to all primitive Pythagorean triples, and areas of non-primitives are square multiples, it follows that this applies to all leg lengths of right triangles, and therefore rectangles.